# How should I use android:configChanges when determining orientation

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

Currently I am handling orientation in my live wallpaper with my service settings in the manifest set to:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

I've heard some people say I should be using:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
```

Note -- I am using some custom code inside the `onConfigurationChanged()` method

What is the correct way I should be doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> android:configChanges
>       Lists configuration changes that the activity will handle itself. When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute will prevent the activity from being restarted. Instead, the activity remains running and its onConfigurationChanged() method is called.

So if you need to manage only the rotation, the keyboard flag is useless since documentation says:

> "keyboard"    The keyboard type has changed — for example, the user has plugged in an external keyboard

the `onConfigurationChanged()`  callback is called when the event occurs. So it is correct that your custom code is inside the callback self.